# Not sure whether to use singular or plural

Tags: singular-vs-plural, compound-subjects

Is it correct to write

> happiness and prosperity **are the result** of diligent work

or

> happiness and prosperity **are the results** of diligent work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the singular or the plural depending on your intended meaning. If you mean that diligent work produces the combination of happiness and prosperity, then you can use the singular "result". If you mean that diligent hard work produces happiness and also produces prosperity, then you can use the plural "results". Both sentences are grammatical. The difference is subtle and conceptual.